# Is electorate on a different update schedule, or am I under review?

Tags: support, badges

So I am mostly just curious, but having a gold badge would be rad. I think I qualify for the [Electorate], but I could be wrong;

`Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions`

And right now I am at:

[image: am I being investigated? or is time not on my side?]

Anyway, just curious since I think I ticked over two days ago, and nothing updated. Could someone let me know if my votes are being audited or something?

Comment: Every time an electorate badge is given, an unicorn loses its corn. Do you want this to happen?

Comment: @kiam But then the uni can become anything it desires, like a uni-cycle, and that is a beautiful thing

Comment: So a unicode is a unicorn that writes code, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've got your criteria wrong. You have to vote for 600 questions. You've only voted for 218. It's not 600 votes with 25% being questions, it's 600 votes on questions with at least 25% of total votes being on questions. So you could get the badge with 600 total votes if they're all on questions or with 2400 votes with 600 on questions, but if you have 4000 votes, you'd need at least 1000 of them to be on questions to get the badge.

It confused me to no end at first too.

You still need almost 400 votes on questions to get the badge.

Comment: Man that is worded horribly. Does "Cast at least 600 votes on questions, constituting at least 25% of total votes" make more sense, or am I just barely literate?

Comment: While I can't comment on your over all literacy level ;o), I agree it is terrible wording and your suggestion is much clearer.

Comment: [I found the meta.se for this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/clarify-electorate-badge-wording/34351#34351); apparently we are not alone in not quite understanding the verbage.